# The beginning of the beginning - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

The beginning of the beginning and start of all,
The beginning of the beginning and part of a call.
I bring pain and suffering, but lots of love.
I cause serious foolishness, but am pure as a dove.
Some love me, some hate me, what about you?
But realize without me, there'd be nothing to do.
Confusion,frustration I bring, but white as a lamb,
Can you riddle out what it is that I am?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a:

> Baby?

The beginning of the beginning and start of all,

> Spelling starts with BA

The beginning of the beginning and part of a call.

> The meaning of life began and a cry out during labor  **EDIT: Spelling continue with B and Y - part of a cry (call)**

I bring pain and suffering, but lots of love.

> Labor brings pain and suffering, but lots of love to the new born

I cause serious foolishness, but am pure as a dove.

> A negative correlation between fertility and intelligence has been argued to have existed.  A baby is pure as a dove.

Some love me, some hate me, what about you?

> There are people that doesn't like babies.

But realize without me, there'd be nothing to do.

> Without being born, there'd be nothing to do.

Confusion,frustration I bring, but white as a lamb,
Can you riddle out what it is that I am?

> Annoying crying babies

Comment: Very nice! You aren't quite there with the second clue. Build on the first one you did.

Comment: @AggieKidd Edited the answer, see if that fits!  Also, like the connection between the spelling of BABY and the meaning of "the beginning of the beginning" in first 2 lines

Comment: Very nicely done!